# Image editing control for WinRT XAML applications

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Apparently Aviary used to provide an image editing control for windows store apps, but they have discontinued it:
http://www.neowin.net/news/aviary-stops-image-editing-sdk-support-for-windows-phone-and-windows-8

I'm already successfully using their iOS SDK offering and now find myself in need of a similar control for WinRT, but would like to try and avoid using a discontinued solution (assuming that's even possible/allowed).

Does anyone know of any other ready-made control which is specifically able to let the user draw lines (like with a brush) and write text over an image the same as Aviary does?

Comment: Component one Imaging for WinRT xaml? http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ImagingWinRT/

Comment: Thanks, but apparently their control does not provide the required functionality.

Comment: I dont know about a ready-made control but Nokia Image SDK is easy to use and you should probably look into it: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk/quick-start/qs-w81-wp81.html
However the SDK only works with Universal apps. Best of Luck!